# sequence proof that $b_{n+1}<b_n$ and $a_{n+1}>a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $ \{a_n\}_{n \geq 0},\{b_n\}_{n \geq 0}  $ be two sequences. The sequences are given as $ b_n:= \dfrac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}2 $ $a_n = \frac{c}{b_{n}} $ for $n \geq 1$ with $b_0 = b $ and $a_0 = \dfrac{c}{b}$.

I know that: $$ \frac{a_{0}+b_{0}}{2} > \sqrt{a_{0}b_{0}} $$

And I already proofed that: $$ a_n < \sqrt{c} < b_n  $$

I want to show that for all integers $n$: $b_{n+1}<b_n$ and $a_{n+1}>a_n$ and that: $b_n-a_n \le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cdot (b_1-a_1) $

I started with:
$b_{n} > \sqrt{c} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a_{n+1}b_{n+1}}} >  \frac{c}{0.5({a_{n+1}b_{n+1})}} = \frac{c}{b_{n+2}}$

But I don't know how to go on :/
Can someone help? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Forgot to prove $b_n>b_{n+1}$. This is because $a_n < c < b_n$, so $b_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2}<\frac{b_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2}=b_{n-1}$.

---

$$2(b_n-a_n)=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}-2a_n \le a_{n-1}+b_{n-1} - 2a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}-a_{n-1}$$
The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Ok but how to proof: $b_{n+1}<b_n$ ?

Comment: Sorry just added.

Comment: But how can I do the induction for 2(b_n - a_n) ?

Comment: $b_n-a_n \le \frac 12 (b_{n-1}-a_{n-1}) \le \frac 14 (b_{n-2}-a_{n-2}) \le \cdots $ etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you have to suppose that $b^2 \neq c$ if you want to write strict inequalities.
To show that $b_{n+1} \leq b_n$, write
$$b_{n+1} - b_n = \frac{a_n - b_n}{2}$$
and this is negative since $a_n \leq b_n$. The fact that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ follows. To show that $b_n - a_n \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} (b_1 - a_1)$, write for $n > 1$,
\begin{align*}
b_n - a_n & = \frac{a_{n - 1} + b_{n - 1}}{2} - a_n \\
& \leq \frac{a_{n - 1} + b_{n - 1}}{2} - a_{n - 1} \\
& = \frac{b_{n - 1} - a_{n - 1}}{2}
\end{align*}
and conclude by induction.